# SSIS How Do I Email an Error Caught in a VB Script

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that sends an email when a task fails, letting me know the name of the task.  I'm trying to get more specific errors.  I've added the code below to my VB script task, but I never get the error.

I have a string variable set to hold the error, [User::EmailError].  I have this variable set in my task as ReadWriteVariables.  I have the code below to capture the error and place it into the variable.  I also have the script task property 'FailPackageOnFailure' set to true.

```
  Try
        smtpServer.Send(email)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dts.Variables("EmailError").Value = ex.ToString
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    End Try
```

I have an OnError event handler setup for the script task with a send mail task using the following expression for the messagsource.

```
"The Send User Email script failed with the following error:"
+@[User::EmailError]
```

I get the email but the variable is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my script was generating an error when assigning a 'To' email address to the mail message, which was outside the Try/Catch.  I moved the Try and the error was caught and emailed successfully.